# Trouble creating a slider using skewed containers

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a slider where the slides have skewed containers. However, because of the transformation, I am having a difficult time getting the math to work correctly. The issue seems to be that using `outerWidth` I am still getting 100px for the width of the slides, but with the skew, the actual width is more like 112px.

```js
$(function() {

  var sliderInnerPos = $('.slider-inner').position().left;
  var slideWidth = $('.slide').outerWidth();
  
  console.log(slideWidth);

  $('.slider-nav span').click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('left')) {
      sliderInnerPos += slideWidth;
    } else {
      sliderInnerPos -= slideWidth;
    }
    
    $('.slider-inner').css('left', sliderInnerPos);
  });
});
```

```css
.slide-container {
  width:400px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.slider-inner {
  min-width:3000px;
  position:relative;
  left:18px;
  -webkit-transition:all .5s;
          transition:all .5s;
}

.slide {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:black;
  float:left;
  margin-left:30px;
  -webkit-transform:skewX(7deg);
          transform:skewX(7deg);
}
  .slide:first-child {
    margin-left:0;
  }
.slider-nav {
  width:400px;
  margin-top:20px;
}
.slider-nav > span {
  display:inline-block;
  width:50%;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:20px;
  font-weight:bold;
  cursor:pointer;
  margin-left:-4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide-container">
  <div class="slider-inner">
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="slider-nav">
  <span class="left"><</span>
  <span class="right">></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the skew, it's the left margin. Just add 30px or calculate the outerWidth of the last element (not the first, since you strip the margin off the first). You can pass `true` as first parameter of `.outerWidth()` to include margin in the width calculations.

```js
$(function() {

  var sliderInnerPos = $('.slider-inner').position().left;
  var slideWidth = 30 + $('.slide').outerWidth(); // first option, manually add +30px to accommodate for margin
  var slideWidth = $('.slide:last').outerWidth(true); // second option, get outer width including margin of last .slide
  
  console.log(slideWidth);

  $('.slider-nav span').click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('left')) {
      sliderInnerPos += slideWidth;
    } else {
      sliderInnerPos -= slideWidth;
    }
    
    $('.slider-inner').css('left', sliderInnerPos);
  });
});
```

```css
.slide-container {
  width:400px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.slider-inner {
  min-width:3000px;
  position:relative;
  left:18px;
  -webkit-transition:all .5s;
          transition:all .5s;
}

.slide {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:black;
  float:left;
  margin-left:30px;
  -webkit-transform:skewX(7deg);
          transform:skewX(7deg);
}
  .slide:first-child {
    margin-left:0;
  }
.slider-nav {
  width:400px;
  margin-top:20px;
}
.slider-nav > span {
  display:inline-block;
  width:50%;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:20px;
  font-weight:bold;
  cursor:pointer;
  margin-left:-4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide-container">
  <div class="slider-inner">
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="slider-nav">
  <span class="left"><</span>
  <span class="right">></span>
</div>
```